# Deploy the war compiled in Windows to Weblogic on Linux

Tags: java, linux, eclipse, weblogic-10.x

I am the beginner on Weblogic. I have the war file made by eclipse in Windows side. How can I deploy this war to Weblogic 10.3.3 on Linux directly? What settings/changes should be noticed?

Answer (score 1):

As weblogic is a JavaEE compliant server, as long as you didn't do anything out of the ordinary or use system specific resources, then you should be able to open the weblogic admin console and deploy it without any side effects.